# Cake PHP 2 Model association with finder query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a scenario where I have to associate the same model with hasMany.

My Table structure:[image]

Has to Many relation for `Children` in `PatientPaymentTransaction` Model:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'Children' => [
      'className' => 'PatientPaymentTransaction',
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'dependent' => true,
     // 'conditions' => ['Children.reference_id' => 'PatientPaymentTransaction.transaction_id' ],
      'fields' => '',
      'order' => '',
      'limit' => '',
      'offset' => '',
      'exclusive' => '',
      'finderQuery' => 'SELECT *,children.reference_id as patient_payment_transaction_id FROM patient_payment_transactions children WHERE children.reference_id = {$__cakeID__$}',
      'counterQuery' => ''
    ]
  ];
```

The response

[image]

The data is found but not appended in children.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it like this, inside the Model I am working my relationship `$hasMany` is laid out like this:

```
       'PatientPaymentTransaction' => array(
            'className' => 'PatientPaymentTransaction',
            'foreignKey' => 'reference_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => 'SELECT *,children.reference_id from children FROM patient_payment_transactions children WHERE children.reference_id = {$__cakeID__$}',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        );
```